# Invertible Matrix Row Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that A and B are n × n matrices and that A is invertible. Show that AB has the same row space as B.

How would I go about proving this statement? I said that the multiplication of two square matrices creates a matrix with the same row space, however, I was told that was not right.

Comment: What's your textbook's (or notes') definition of row-space?

Comment: To see why the row spaces don't need to be the same if $A$ is not invertible, take $B = I$ and $A = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** depending on which is closer to your definition, for a column vector $x$, note one of the following:

- $x^TAB = (x^TA)B$
- $(AB)^Tx = B^T(A^Tx)$